# Authenticated encryption with Enc-Sign-Mac

Tags: encryption, signature, mac, authenticated-encryption

I've given a CPA secure private key encryption scheme, an unforgeable private key MAC scheme and an unforgeable public key signature scheme. I want to combine them to protect confidentiality, integrity and authenticity. I have to use the signature scheme, such that some third party can prove authenticity and integrity of the message. I tried it this way:

$c \gets \operatorname{Enc}_{ke}(m)$

$\sigma \gets \operatorname{Sign}_{sk}(c)$

$t \gets \operatorname{MAC}_{km}(c||σ)$

$\operatorname{Output} (c,t,σ)$

Does this protect the mentioned properties or: Is there any problem with Enc-Sign-Mac?

Comment: MAC's are generally symmetric. In that case we generally use the term "secret key". But if you already have a secret key, then you can use that to perform authenticated encryption. I'm not saying that this question is bad; it's about understanding when to use the primitives, but be aware that this is a theoretical construction.

Comment: What particular means does the third party have to prove those measures?

Comment: Enc-Sign-Mac doesn't hide the sender's identity from eavesdroppers. ​ ​

Comment: Is there any better way to combine authenticated encryption with signatures?

Comment: Sign-enc-mac could work, provided you want to distribute a secret key to the third party.

Comment: I'm in an juristical context. The third party can be someone who does not have the right to see plaintext. It would be nice if the third party does not need some secret key for verification.

Comment: Who will the third party be proving "authenticity and integrity of the message" to? ​ (A different third party?) ​ Is "the message" the plaintext or the ciphertext? ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: I'd use sign-then-authenticated-encryption, where authenticated encryption may be built using encrypt-then-MAC.

Comment: The third part should be able to prove that to another party. The message is in plaintext. I did it with sign-then-authenticated-encryption. The only problem is, that the third party can't verify the signature without knowing the secret keys.

Comment: @LukasSchüßler : ​ ​ ​ Is "authenticity and integrity of the" plaintext in the sense of [ciphertext decrypts to a proper plaintext]? ​ Otherwise, what you're after would seem to conflict with IND-CPA. ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: Maybe authenticity AND integrity is wrong in the question. I think the verifier of a signature should just be able to verify the sender of a message because the MAC's preserve integrity.